# AngularJS code only works when ng-app=""

Tags: angularjs

The following html page works when ng-app="" but not when ng-app="MyApp". How can I make this page work with ng-app="MyApp"?

The code in this page will print out the text being input as user types into the textbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="MyApp">
    <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
    <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name" value="John"></p>
    <p ng-bind="name"></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried including following JavaScript in this page, but still it did not work.

```
  <script>
     angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['MyApp']);
    });
  </script>
```

**UPDATE 1**

The following script did the trick, which I picked up after reading various responses to my post. I added this just before the closing 'body' tag.

```
<script>
  angular.module('MyApp', []);
</script>
```

Comment: Please, show your app.js code

Comment: Where is your JS code? The HTML page doesn't contain any JS code, and doesn't have any script except the one loading angular. Do you have a module named MyApp? Is there any error in the console?

Comment: to add to the above, you have no need for `angular.bootstrap` if you are not using something like requirejs; angular will automatically load the correct module based on `ng-app` **if** the module is created once the document has finished loading.

Comment: @eyp - There is no app.js code, just the plain html code as pasted here which works when ng-app = ""

Comment: @JBNizet - There is no error when I look up in Console for Google Chrome Developer Tools. Do I need to have something else just because I have provided a name to ng-app rather than an empty string for ng-app?

Comment: @Sunil, if you don't have declared an angular module called MyApp, it's impossible that it works with an MyApp module, don't you think?

Comment: Yes. ng-app="foo" tells angular to configure and run the module "foo". So if there is no module "foo", it makes no sense. Read the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Comment: @JBNizet - Can you paste some sample code in a separate post related to my sample html page?

Comment: The documentation has plenty of code samples. Read it.

Comment: @JBNizet - Yes, thanks you pointed me in the right direction. I have the solution now as mentioned under 'UPDATE 1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your module in Angular. You must declare it in javascript whithin your file:

```
angular.module('MyApp', []);
```

Here you have a good starting tutorial:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/index.html#angularjs-hello-world

Comment: It gives an error now that says: "Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/nomod?p0=MyApp"

Comment: It worked if I added an empty array  like in :  " angular.module('MyApp', []); " rather than " angular.module('MyApp'); "

Comment: the empty array is required.  That array tells the module what other modules are required for it to work, a sort of dependency injection.